# Extend Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online)

Tags: c#, api, wcf, tfs, azure-devops

I am looking for possibilities to extend a standard view of workitem/backlog item page. Basically I would like to add some additional fields. Right now there are Fields like:

- Assigned to
- State
- History
- ...

I don't have access to the TFS server. I've got access just to the website/api. I think that to do this I would have to query API and get all the tfs data and copy it to my database, synchronize that database with a website every 30 min and build some kind of interface on the top of it.

Do you think that there are better ways to do this without duplicating tfs website using a webapi? I was thinking about Lightswitch and Odata/WCF RIA Service so I don't have to deal with the synchronization process and I can just query the tfs data on the fly? Does tfs support this?

If it doesn't what is the best way to copy the Team Services workitems view?

If you have any ideas how to use a tfs data with some customized interface then please let me know.

Comment: When you say you don't have access to the TFS server, do you mean you can't access it physically, or you can't connect to it?  If you can connect to it, you should be able to use the TFS API to do all the querying you need.

Comment: TFS itself can be extended with additional fields and work item types. Through extensions it's possible to extend Visual Studio team Services (the cloud version of of TFS). Extensions and simple process template customization are coming to TFS as well at some point (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx) I think sycning to an external database is a bad idea, unless you need things that can't be done wih standard extension features.

Comment: I meant that I don't have admin access to the server. I do have access to the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you want to do by [modifying the process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782.aspx). This will allow you to add additional work item types, add additional fields to existing work items, and generally alter the way work items appear and are managed.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I am looking for. I have an access to the customer tfs online website. I cannot change their process. If the modifying process template would affect only certain users, then this is something closer to what I am looking for.